# Swift - animating UIImageView image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiimageview

just a quick issue I'm having regarding animating a moving background image for my current application setup. Essentially I want to have my currently still background image scroll from left to right endlessly across my view; but I'm struggling piecing it all together. From a variety of various other sources I've comprised this function that isn't currently working, and i really can't figure out how or why.

```
func animate(_ image: UIImageView) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            image.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -100, y: 0)
        }) { (success: Bool) in
            image.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.animate(image)
        }
    }
```

Any help/assistance is immensely appreciated!

Comment: what kind of animation do you need? explain clearly

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity! I'm desiring my animation to be something along the lines of this; https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/279765/screenshots/1335470/marioscroll_real_real.gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `CAffineTranform` inside `animateWithDuration`, you can simply define the new center like:

```
let oldCenter = image.center
let newCenter = CGPoint(x: oldCenter.x - 100, y: oldCenter.y)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
  image.center = newCenter
}) { (success: Bool) in
  print("Done moving image")
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: After trying to implement your suggestion i'm suggested to adjust the code as follows:           let oldCenter = background.center
        let newCenter = CGRect(origin: oldCenter.x - 100, size: oldCenter.y)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            background.center = newCenter
        }) { (success: Bool) in
            print("Done moving image")
        }
But then i am given a binary operator error as "-" cannot be applied to type "Int" or "CGFloat"

Comment: Sorry my bad it's CGPoint not CGRect. Try with CGPoint now

Comment: Definitely progress in the animation. It slowly starts sliding to the left then stops about 1/6th away through the image. On top of this, it doesn't seem to be re-appearing from the right side of the image; so i do i implement this functionality?

Comment: You will need to adjust the values by trial and error here. Plus you can get rid of delay and options for linear animation. Also decrease the duration to 1 or 2

Comment: Yeah just adjusted settings then; image is successfully sliding off-screen, just isn't re-appearing whatsoever

Comment: Implementation isn't allowing the UIImageView to re-appear to make the animation seem endless. How would i go about implementing this (i.e; making it re-appear before part of it goes off screen

Comment: You can use the completion handler for animateWithDuration method to achieve that.

Comment: Or you can use multiple images on UIImageView and animate then using CALayer.

Comment: How would i go about implementing a completion handler that i would achieve my desired outcome?